# How can I test guitar effects box without a guitar?

Tags: guitar-pedal

I want to play around with guitar effects circuits on a breadboard, but I don't have a guitar. How can I test my circuits without a guitar?

Comment: You can get virtual guitars that run on a PC. Take the line out and maybe attenuate a bit and that should do it.

Comment: @Andyaka, does the sound card audio out signal resemble the guitar signal?

Comment: To the untrained ear they sound OK and I would expect the line out to be reasonably representative. You could always download a few snippets of guitar from free websites but these may already have effects on them. Try searching for "dry" guitar sounds.

Answer (score 2):

As Andy said, the easiest way is to use a line out from your PC. However, there is an important caveat here:

The output impedance of the line out is drastically different from a guitar pickup output. Guitar pickups (and the associated tone/volume circuit) have a very high output impedance, often at least 10kΩ. With the volume and tone controls at midrange, the output impedance may be much higher, in the realm of 100kΩ. This is why most guitar effects are designed with a very high impedance input stage, typ. 250k-1MΩ.

The consequence of this is that you might have a situation where you test a circuit with a PC line out and it works fine, but when using a guitar, it's almost inaudible or has massively reduced high end. This is because your circuit may present much to low of a load for the guitar to adequately drive, while the line out has no trouble.

So, as long as you make sure that you have a sufficiently high input impedance in your guitar effect circuits, a PC line output will be reasonably close. You will want to attenuate it; a guitar output might swing +/-1V or +/-2V with hot pickups, but the line out might be able to drive much more than that, so you should keep the volume pretty low on the PC for a fair representation. What's best is if you can record yourself playing a guitar directly into an audio interface without any post-processing, and play that back (yes, I know you don't have a guitar so this might not be an option), because most stuff you download will have at least some post-processing that changes the dynamics.

Comment: How do I get the output of the circuit? Plug it into the line-in? (I don't have a guitar amplifier)

Comment: Sounds like you've got quite a shopping list. If you've got a set of powered bookshelf speakers, that might work. Or yes, you could run it back into your computer, but you'll need some special software routing to get audio playback and the input monitoring to be separate. Keep in mind that some guitar effects are designed to overdrive the input of an amplifier, and you will not be able to test this (overdriving a regular line input won't be the same, it will probably sound horrid).

Answer (score 1):

There are plenty of royalty free guitar sample sites around where you can download free samples. Try and download ones that are specified as "dry" as these are likely to be less affected by any effects like reverb or distortion. But it little bit of distortion won't be a big deal for some home made effects.

Once you have the samples play back through your line out on your PC. You may need to attenuate a little but messing around is all part of the fun.

There's even [**this**](http://www.adamsguitar.com/) virtual guitar site where you can strum across strings.

Comment: What's the purpose of attenuating? Software attenuation?

Comment: Software attenuation is fine but feed from your line out to your circuit via 47 kohm for a general representation of the impedance of a guitar pick up.

Answer (score 1):

You need to simulate a guitar signal. This has become a rather a common phenomenon.  The technique is called "re-amping". You can take a line-level audio signal and make it into a signal that simulates a guitar output.  You will find many "re-amp" products for sale. And the circuit is simple enough that many people DIY their own.

Ref: https://www.google.com/search?q=re-amp+circuit